# Q: Kubernetes Install on CoreOS showing Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine. May 20 13:06:52 localhost systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency' when I do a systemctl status docker.

Using the CoreOS install documentation, Kubelet(master) all on same node.

Where would I start looking to debug this from?

Comment: core@localhost ~/bin $ sudo systemctl status  docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib64/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─40-flannel.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com

Comment: It looks like flannel didn't start? I'm not totally clear. `journalctl` will give you log output of these apps, that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Andy!  

When I do a core@localhost /bin $ systemctl status flannel
● flannel.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)  

core@localhost /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d $ cat 40-flannel.conf
[Unit]
Requires=flanneld.service
After=flanneld.service

Yet - Core@localhost /bin $ sudo systemctl start flannel
Failed to start flannel.service: Unit flannel.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Comment: And what about journalctl? It's kind of difficult to read what your'e pasting

Comment: Yeah sorry, edit field doesn't display it well.  Its complaining about not being able to connect to the API-Server
journalctl
-- Logs begin at Fri 2016-05-20 12:28:06 UTC, end at Fri 2016-05-20 16:30:07 UTC. --
May 20 12:28:06 localhost rkt[2557]: 2016-05-20 12:28:06,091 [INFO][2609/140603975137968] urllib3.connectionpool 213: Starting new HTTP connection (3): X.X.142.14
[ERROR][2609/140603975137968] calico.etcddriver.driver 296: Request to etcd failed:
Etcd is started though and its on the same machine.

Comment: What is? Flannel connects to etcd, docker is probably set up to require flannel (probably). I don't believe either rely on the kubernetes API server

Comment: I have no additional nodes, all (Kubelet, proxy, scheduler, controller, api and etcd) are on the same machine. Its a CoreOS vm running latest stable version,

Comment: The service name is flanneld, not flannel.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little late, but I think you need to ensure `flanneld.service` service is running. If you're following the CoreOS step-by-step documentation for building a Kubernetes cluster with CoreOS, then flanneld is a dependency for the docker engine.

If you made a systemd drop-in replacement in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/40-flannel.conf`, then that is most likely the case as evidenced here:

`[Unit]
Requires=flanneld.service
After=flanneld.service`